# Process variable from MYSQL static string

Tags: laravel, variables, laravel-5.3

I save Title page template in MYSQL
like string

> Range ($code_ranges->code) $code_ranges->from - $code_ranges->to

in Controller i call

```
$title = $webDomain->titlePhoneRangePage;
```

and pass $title to view but in view i see this line

> Range ($code_ranges->code) $code_ranges->from - $code_ranges->to

but i want see processed varible

> Range (203) 10000000 - 90000000

how i can Process varible from mysql in controller?
i need storage this on mysql

Thank a lot!

Comment: Are you saving "Range ($code_ranges->code) $code_ranges->from - $code_ranges->to" as `titlePhoneRangePage` in the database? Also, can you show your `WebDomain` model?

Comment: standart model
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class domains extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'domains';
    //
}